# MSP430 Problems with compatibility

Tags: c, msp430, texas-instruments

I'm using an MSP430 Launchpad. To be more specific I'm using the microcontroler MS430G2553. I was trying to compile some code designed for the MS430G2230 but the problem is that some parts of the code wont match the MS430G2553.
This is the code

```
void USI_Init (void)
{
 // configure SPI
 USICTL0 |= USISWRST;                      // USI in reset
 USICTL0 = USICTL0 | USILSB;               // Least Significant Bit first
 USICTL0 |= USIPE7 + USIPE6 + USIPE5 + USIMST + USIOE; // Port, SPI Master
 USICTL1 |= USICKPH;                       // flag remains set
 USICKCTL = USIDIV_1 + USISSEL_2;          // /2 SMCLK
 USICTL0 &= ~USISWRST;                     // USI released for operation
 USICNT = USICNT | 0x50;                   // 16 bit mode; 16 bit to be    transmitted/received
 return;
}
```

and this is the second routine that doesn't work

```
#pragma vector=WDT_VECTOR
__interrupt void Write_Matrix(void)
{
static unsigned char index=0;

 P1OUT |= DATA_LATCH_PIN;
 P1OUT &= ~DATA_LATCH_PIN;

  USICTL1 &= ~USIIFG;           // Clears the interrupt flag
  USISRH = 1<<index;            // Move the index of the column in the high bits of USISR
  USISRL = Matrix[index];       // Move the index of the rows (value of Matrix[index]) in the low bits of USIRS
  USICNT = USICNT | 0x10;       // 16 bit format
 index = (index+1) & 7;

 return;
}
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't expect to have code that is 100% portable between those two families of processors. The MSP430G2553 is a much larger value line processor and comes with more peripherals than the MSP430G2230.

Please refer to the following diagrams:

### MSP430G2230 Functional Diagram

[image: MSP430G2230 Functional Diagram]

### MSP430G2553 Functional Diagram

[image: MSP430G2553 Functional Diagram]

As you can see, these MCUs are very different.

Your first routine doesn't work because the MSP430G2553 doesn't have a `USI` peripheral. Instead, SPI communication is performed using  a `USCI` peripheral. You will need to modify your code to use this peripheral instead. Please reference the [User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slau144&fileType=pdf) for more information.

Your second routine doesn't work because of the lack of `USI` peripheral again. Notice the references to `USI` registers: `USICTL1 &= ~USIIFG;`, etc. You will need to once again modify your code to use the `USCI` peripheral.